# SQL one select with different where clauses

Tags: sql

i need to do one select with different where clauses (with different product code). The result which i need is below.

**I have table like:**

```
ApID | Date       | Code | Qty | Price | Sum
222  | 2014-10-11 | 555  | 1   | 2,22  | 2,22
222  | 2014-10-11 | 555  | 1   | 2,22  | 2,22
222  | 2014-10-11 | 333  | 1   | 3,33  | 3,33
222  | 2014-10-12 | 555  | 1   | 2,22  | 2,22
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT 
CAST(Date AS DATE) as 'Data',
SUM(Qty*Price) AS 'Sum',
SUM(Qty) AS 'Qty'
  FROM Table
  WHERE ApID = 222
  AND Data BETWEEN '2014-10-11' AND '2014-10-13' 
  AND Code LIKE '555'
GROUP BY CAST(KvitoGalva.Data AS DATE)
```

**I get result like this:**

```
Data       | Sum  | Qty
2014-10-11 | 4.44 | 2
2014-10-12 | 2.22 | 1
```

**I need to display result in one table:**

```
Data       | Sum 555  | Qty 555 | Sum 333 | Qty 333 |
2014-10-11 | 4.44     | 2       | 3.33    | 1       |
2014-10-12 | 2.22     | 1       | 0       | 0       |
```

Tried:

```
SELECT((Select1),(Select2))
----------------------------
SELECT 1
union
select 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CAST(Date AS DATE) as Data,
       SUM(case when code = '555' then Qty*Price else 0 end) AS Sum555,
       SUM(case when code = '555' then Qty else 0 end) AS Qty555,
       SUM(case when code = '333' then Qty*Price else 0 end) AS Sum333,
       SUM(case when code = '333' then Qty else 0 end) AS Qty333
FROM Table t
WHERE ApID = 222 AND
      Data BETWEEN '2014-10-11' AND '2014-10-13' AND
      Code IN ('555', '333')
GROUP BY CAST(KvitoGalva.Data AS DATE);
```

Note:  only use single quotes for string and date constants.  You do not need quotes for column aliases and if you did, then your database would have a better character for escaping the names.